# GitHubCli has no command called "pr"

Tags: github

I'm trying to checkout a pull request locally

The [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally) tell you to use:

```
gh pr checkout *pull-request*
```

But this gives me the result:

```
Usage: gh [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try "gh --help" for help.

Error: No such command "pr".
```

I don't know what version of GitHubCli I am using because gh version has a similar error.

```
Usage: gh [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try "gh --help" for help.

Error: No such command "version".
```

Other commands seem to work as expected, for example "me" and "issue"

Comment: What version of `gh` is that? The message from mine when I use a non-existing command looks like `unknown command "blah" for "gh"` and `Usage:  gh <command> <subcommand> [flags]`

Comment: Oh, you wrote you can't see the version. How did you install `gh`?

Comment: Are you typing these commands, or copy-pasting them? If the latter, can you try typing? Maybe there's invisible characters messing things up.

Comment: @Benjamin W. I figured it out. I installed with homebrew on linux. By using "brew install gh" I was able to get the latest version. pr and version commands now work as expcted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your using [gitsome](https://github.com/donnemartin/gitsome), which is another GitHub client that also provides a `gh` command. The documentation is for the [official GitHub client](https://github.com/cli/cli). The official client is available for maxOS, Linux, and Windows. You'll have to follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/cli/cli#installation) for your platform.